# bootstrap failure to render "fa fa-logoimage" such as twitter, facebook, linkedin

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following classes in index.html.erb not rendering the related Icons in a Ruby on Rails homepage built with a startbootstrap.com "Agency" template.

I have: 
- named and renamed the font-awesome.css.erb & font-awesome.min.css.erb to xx.css.scss.erb 
- and back,
- replaced the necessary code in font-awesome.css.erb.
- All caches cleared, tested in Chrome & Firefox,

ISSUE: the icons for Twitter, Facebook and Linked in are not showing.  All else is working.  Is there something about the "fa fa-**" that is not right?

I would like to know what I am missing?

```
      <h4>Team Member</h4>
   <p class="text-muted">Designer</p>
   <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="team-member">
      <img src="assets/team/2.jpg
```

Comment: Is font-awesome loaded in the console?

Comment: Have you installed the gem? And have you imported the related css to your scss/less files?

Comment: In your application.css, include the css file:

/*
 *= require font-awesome
 */

Comment: I have installed Gem, as part of the